# How to create text file from collections and save it in SD in Android mobiles using meteorjs

Tags: javascript, cordova, meteor

How to create text file by reading data from collections and save it to Internal memory in Android mobiles using meteorjs.

When I click generate button, a text file should create and save to sd card or internal memory with my specific folder. This is an offline android app, so there is no server connection and file creation should be done in **client** side only.

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

There is a Cordova plugin:

cordova-plugin-file

This plugin implements a File API allowing read/write access to files residing on the device.